# How should I address a question/answer that indirectly answered another question without it being asked?

Tags: discussion

I make it a habit that whenever I have a question, I first dig up answers already given to that question or to similar questions (for obvious reasons, hope I didn't miss on this case), and a lot of times I've found answers to what I need in questions and answers that are almost unrelated to my question, (e.g. a certain exception that popped up and 'gave me a clue'), I'm guessing it partially happens because the search matches keywords, etc.

In those cases I usually up-vote (the Q or the A or both), but the chance to share a solution to another problem that someone might encounter seems lost.

Leaving a comment is not enough (it's small, not everybody reads them, and it can get lost if comments stack up), and it would be inappropriate to ask and answer myself in this case.

EDIT:
Asking and immediately answering myself - it seems inappropriate to me in this case, since it feels a little like "working the reputation system" - I'm not asking a question while researching the solution, I'm asking a question while already having the answer ready, am I wrong to see it that way?

How should I go about these cases?

Comment: What do you think it would be inappropriate to ask and answer yourself? The way you phrase it, the 'answer' you saw wasn't specific to your situation and had you work out the remaining details. The whole problem set and solution sounds like something you could share.

Comment: @Trobbins: Some crazies would vote to close that sort of question as a dupe in an instant.

Comment: if you have the same question or bad question, then don't  ask here

Comment: It's not the same question - in that case the upvote is obvious, and it's not necessarily a bad question, but the solution might partially come up when looking through other questions that are unrelated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing is Upvote that answer and describe in comment where its useful for you also, if small enough.

And if your question is bit different where  you found answer, the ask another question, and add your descriptive answer to your question with include reference to original answer.

Don't ask new question, if you have the same problem where you are referring to answer itself.